Where do the oxide compounds originally come from (or how do they get there) to cause purple dirt and solid material within that dirt?
I saw the thread on purple dirt. I was digging at a depth of between 3' and 4' in my yard and amongst the tons of river rock I came up on purple dirt and then lots of a solid material that looks sort of like what a metal that was melted and then dripped on itself might look like. It's heavy and very scratchy or rough to touch - not quite sharp, but on the verge... I filled 2 5 gallon buckets with the dirt and material. The hole it created from digging it out is about another foot deep and probably 2' feet around, maybe 3' but in a perfect circle. If this is one of the oxide compounds discussed in the purple dirt thread, where could it have come from? How did it get there? How do I figure out exactly what it is? There are also rocks within the area that look like they've been exposed to a high temperature as they are bright red, black and greyish white instead of the layers of oranges and browns I've seen in all the other broken rocks I've dug out in my little project/venture I have going to have discovered this spot... The material is also shades of purples and or reds. -All of it. I think I've found some coal in with it, as it is a black color but as the previously mentioned thread said, it could be another compound. The dirt in my yard is primarily clay with so many rocks of all sizes that I think could mean there was a river here some years ago. (How could I find out if that were correct and the possible date or time period of this?) I also secretly hoped I'd found a long ago crashed meteorite! (I have some pictures but I don't think I can add them, unfortunately.)
I am SO curious about the whole thing and I appreciate any input anyone may have to help me out!! Thank you so much!  **P.S. I live in Mid-Northeastern Ohio.

A photo of what you talk about might go a long way. A link to the other thread you refer to, too.
